# Why can't I use a "file" as the "body" of an http request?

Tags: file, http, post, go

"http.Post" expects a "Reader" as the body argument. "File" implements "Reader". 
But if I pass file as the body argument I always receive 0 bytes at the other end. Why?

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("lala.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("file open errrrr %v \n", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    resp, err := http.Post("http://requestb.in/11fta851", "text/plain", file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("errrrr %v \n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("resp code %d \n", resp.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

I know that you could do "file.ReadAll" to a buffer and use that. But it feels like double work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site requestb.in seems to ignore POST data if the header `Content-Length` is not specified. This code works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("lala.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("file open errrrr %v \n", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://requestb.in/1fry3jy1", file)
    req.ContentLength = 5
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("errrrr %v \n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("resp code %d \n", resp.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks!
So the problem is that for "File" the http library does not calculate the  ContentLength.

Comment: Also.. If you want to get the right size of the file you can do: fs, _ := file.Stat(); req.ContentLength = fs.Size()

Comment: @marcel.corso: the http package doesn't calculate ContentLength because http/1.1 uses chunked encoding by default. It up to you to set it if it's required for some reason. The remote server is either incorrectly ignoring chunked transfer encoding, or the api specifically requires a ContentLength.

Comment: @JimB in my search for an answer I stumbled on the thing that the library do calculate the Content-Length for some cases: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0c72eeb121702cc0a820976138cc01dd1a475895/src/net/http/request.go#L568 . But I guess it would be a bad idea to add a another "case" there for file.Stat() since it can fail... be chunked.. etc. thanks!